# How can I fire a react function from a ajax request success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I hope you can help. 
I want to run the **postPaymentHandler** function.

The ajax request gets call after a forms submit button is clicked. The form validates and the ajax request is successful.

When the success function runs, the **this.paymentSuccessful(filteredCatalogue);** function fires the following error: 
***Uncaught TypeError: this.paymentSuccessful is not a function***

```
            submitFormHandler(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var self = this;
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'components/charge.php',
                   data : {
                     stripeToken: token
                   },
                   success: (data) => {
                    this.paymentSuccessful(filteredCatalogue); //This code fires an error in the console.
                  },
                   error: function(data,textStatus) {
                     console.log("Ajax Error!");
                   }
                 });//$.ajax
                };

  //PaymentSuccessful function in root level scope of component.
  paymentSuccessful(){
    this.props.postPaymentHandler(filteredCatalogue);
  };
```

I tried assigning the self variable to this so the function reads **self.props.postPaymentHandler(filteredCatalogue);**. No luck.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is because, the **this** scope, belongs to the **success** function. If you really want to execute the **paymentSuccessful** you have some options:

1) Assign paymentSuccessful outside the **success** scope in a variable, then it will be available to run.

2) Try to bind the ajax function call.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Codes and Tags I was able to make it work.

By setting the **paymentSuccessful** function as a variable **outside** the scope of the success function, the function can reference the intended prop.

The **this** helper needs to be included. That means to assign **this** to a variable.

**var self = this;**

Something that I tried, that **didn't** work was setting the variable inside the **componentDidMount** function.

```
        submitFormHandler(e){

             var self = this;
             e.preventDefault();
             var self = this;
             var paymentSuccessful = function(){
             self.props.postPaymentHandler();
            };

            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'components/charge.php',
               data : {
                 stripeToken: token
               },
               success: (data) => {
                paymentSuccessful(); //This function works as expected
              },
               error: function(data,textStatus) {
                 console.log("Ajax Error!");
               }
             });//$.ajax
            };
```